# Mass weight calculation with a dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I have trouble with this exercise:

I have this dictionary:

```
masas = {'H': 1.007825, 'C': 12.01, 'O': 15.9994, 
         'N': 14.0067, 'S': 31.972071, 'P': 30.973762}
```

My code is:

```
def calcula_masa_atomica(molecula):
    masa = 0.0
    grupos = molecula.split('-')
    for grupo in grupos:
        grupo[0] = masas.keys():
        grupo[1] = masas.values()
    return masa
```

I have tried with

```
print(calcula_masa_atomica('C13-H18-O2'))
```

However, it didn't work. I'm new to Python, and I don't know what is happening

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please describe what "working" entails. What output are you expecting and what did you get? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't assign anything to `masa` variable, so you will always return `0`. You can try this example to get the molecule weight:

```
masas = {
    "H": 1.007825,
    "C": 12.01,
    "O": 15.9994,
    "N": 14.0067,
    "S": 31.972071,
    "P": 30.973762,
}


def calcula_masa_atomica(molecula):
    masa = 0.0
    grupos = molecula.split("-")
    for grupo in grupos:
        masa += masas[grupo[0]] * float(grupo[1:])
    return masa


print(calcula_masa_atomica("C13-H18-O2"))
```

Prints:

```
206.26964999999998
```

---

EDIT: To handle molecules without numbers:

```
masas = {
    "H": 1.007825,
    "C": 12.01,
    "O": 15.9994,
    "N": 14.0067,
    "S": 31.972071,
    "P": 30.973762,
}


def calcula_masa_atomica(molecula):
    masa = 0.0
    grupos = molecula.split("-")
    for grupo in grupos:
        masa += masas[grupo[0]] * float(1 if (x := grupo[1:]) == "" else x)
    return masa


print(calcula_masa_atomica("C-H2-O2"))
```

Prints:

```
46.02445
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. But now, I tried with this one 'C-H2-O2' and it says: ValueError